# Please link to chat room when mod moves comment to chat

Tags: feature-request, comments, chat, hyperlinks, revisions-list

In a recent discussion about a question, a moderator moved the numerous comments to chat, and left a comment with a link to the room.

However, a bunch of us were left wondering why there isn't an automatic link to the room in the revision history, where we're told that a moderator moved comments to chat. I just found out that a link is posted in an automatic comment, but I think that posting it in the revision history is better -- [diamonds are forever](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamonds_Are_Forever_(novel)), comments are not. I've seen posts (no handy link, sorry) where the chat comment had been deleted, leaving a bunch of comments in chat, without a way for anyone to see them.

[image]

**I mean, we already have the "mod moved comments to chat" in revision history; why not linkify that?**

Comment: Most of the time, when I've seen this used, the moderator also leaves a custom comment with a link to the chat room, and *explains why* the comments were moved to chat.  Something to the effect of "[Comments move to chat](http://example.com).  Please stay on-topic here."

Comment: The comment is automatic, not hand-crafted, but comments are volatile.  In particular, the usual workflow with this is: click "move comments to chat", purge all comments, manually undelete the (new) last one with the link to the chat room.  That can go wrong.  We should keep the auto-comment (where it's visible, assuming it's not accidentally deleted) but I agree that *also* linkifying it in the post history would be helpful.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Right, but I've also seen moderators forget to leave that comment. Also, something in the revision history is a lot more permanent than a comment.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Oh, I hadn't realized. Thanks for clarifying that.